# reading text line by line in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I have date.txt file where are codes

ex:

1111111111111111

2222222222222222

3333333333333333

4444444444444444

I want to check each code in website.

i tried:

```
with open('date.txt', 'r') as f:
                data = f.readlines()

                for line in data:
                        words = line.split()
                        send_keys(words)
```

But this copy only last line to.

I need to make a loop that will be checking line by line until check all

thanks for help

4am is to late 4my little brain..

==
edit:
slove

```
while lines > 0:

                    lines = lines - 1  

                    with open('date.txt', 'r') as f:
                        data = f.readlines()
                        words = data[lines]
                        print(words)
```

Comment: while lines > 0:
                    try:
                        lines = lines - 1  
                     
                        with open('date.txt', 'r') as f:
                            data = f.readlines()
                            words = data[lines]
                            print(words)

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think it will work :

```
line_1 = file.readline()

line_2 = file.readline()
```

repeat this for how many lines you would like to read.

One thing to keep in mind is if you print these lines they will all print on the same line.